# Way to present a form - php and HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I am struggling and I don't know where else to turn. I have a customer who sells on their website, however, I am rewriting the code and I need a contact form that sends off a query to them. At present it's all set up in Wordpress.

However, the form will allow the customer to send simple information for one order. So qty, color, description fields are in the form (contact form 7 plugin)

What I want is for them to enter that information as many times for different products. So customer enters eg, 5 blue pyjamas + 10 green socks. But they could have lots of orders and we have no way of knowing how many. What I need is an interface idea that is not too difficult as this is a throw away form until the ecommerce is set up properly. Please let me know if I am not making myself clear.

Comment: Why not keep the form as it is and instead of sending the item as it's entered, add it to a list (and store in hidden `input`s maybe). Then provide a `Submit` button that sends the whole list.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. Thanks Gareth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not validated the code but here is a concept.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ordernum = 1;
    function Add_to_Order() {
        /* Adding another order to the form */
        ordernum++;
        var order_str = '<p><label for="order' + ordernum + '_id">Quantity: </label><input id="order' + ordernum + '_id" name="order' + ordernum + '_qty" type="text" size="6" /><input name="order' + ordernum + '_color" type="text" /><input name="order' + ordernum + '_desc" type="text" /></p>';  
        $('#orders').append(order_str);

        /* Replaces the value of qty so that you know how many orders to track */
        $('input[name=qty]').val(function(index, value) {
           return value.replace(ordernum);
        });
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        /* When add order button is pressed it will add additional fields to the id=orders */
        $('#add_order').click(Add_to_Order);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="">
        <label for="name_id">Name: </label>
        <input id="name_id" name="name" type="text" />
        <fieldset id="orders">
            <p>
                <label for="order1_id">Quantity: </label>
                <input id="order1_id" name="order1_qty" type="text" size="6" />
                <input name="order1_color" type="text" />
                <input name="order1_desc" type="text" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <input id="add_order" type="button" value="Add Another Item" />
        <input id="qty" name="qty" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <hr />
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />      
    </form>
</body>
```

After this point you could validate the form and on submit you can send the information based on the number of qty orders you have.  I would also add some security measures as well but this is just a concept you can work with.

Comment: Thanks, that's not too bad an idea too. Thanks Robert Lee.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the PHP mail form that you want is not easy but I've keep trying to help, even you didn't graph the form that you've wanted, nor even the subject. Now, for example we've a PHP file named *form.php*, here is the PHP script:

```
<?php
$q = addslashes($_GET["q"]);

if (empty($q)) {
    echo '<form action="form.php" method="get">
    How many do you want to order: <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>';
}

if ($q > 0) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['from'])) {
        $from = $_REQUEST['from'] ;

        // place your email here
        $to = "mail@example.com";

        $subject = "Customer: " . $_REQUEST['name'];

        $i = 1;
        while ($i <= $q) {
            $message .= "Order $i\n";
            $message .= "Quality: " . $_REQUEST['quality' . $i] . "\n";
            $message .= "Color: " . $_REQUEST['color' . $i] . "\n";
            $message .= "Description: " . $_REQUEST['description' . $i] . "\n\n";
            $i++;
        }

        $message .= "Note: " . $_REQUEST['note'];
        mail($to, $subject, $message, "From:" . $from);
        echo "Thank you for submitting your order!";
    } else {
        echo "<form method='post'>
        Email: <input name='from' type='text'><br />
        Full Name: <input name='name' type='text'><br />";

        $i = 1;
        while ($i <= $q) {
            echo "Order $i<br />
            Quality: <input name='quality" . $i . "' type='text'><br />
            Color: <input name='color" . $i . "' type='text'><br />
            Description: <input name='description" . $i . "' type='text'><br />";
            $i++;
        }

        echo "Additional Note:<br />
        <textarea name='note' rows='15' cols='40'></textarea><br />
        <input type='submit'>
        </form>";
    }
}
?>
```

That mail form is tested and working.. Just do the rest to improve and to style it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I will go with Robert's idea but thanks for all the time this must have taken you to write.